# TRUE single checkout page on BigCommerce

Tags: javascript, jquery, e-commerce, checkout, bigcommerce

Currently BigCommerce has this hide/show effect only displaying one step of the checkout process at a time. It's rather an annoying accordion. I am trying to have the accordion info all open on the page. Also, I would love to combined and/or change the steps order.  Any help with any of this would be great! Here is an example of the JS being used for the checkout process.

```
var ExpressCheckout = {
completedSteps: new Array(),
currentStep: 'AccountDetails',
signedIn: 0,
digitalOrder: 0,
createAccount: 0,
anonymousCheckout: 0,
checkoutLogin: 0,
init: function()
{
    if($('#CheckoutStepAccountDetails').css('display') == 'none') {
        ExpressCheckout.currentStep = 'BillingAddress';
    }
    else {
        $('#BillingDetailsLabel').html(lang.ExpressCheckoutStepBillingAccountDetails);
    }

    $('.ExpressCheckoutBlock').hover(function() {
        if($(this).hasClass('ExpressCheckoutBlockCompleted')) {
            $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
        }
    },
    function() {
        $(this).css('cursor', 'default');
    });

    $('.ExpressCheckoutTitle').click(function() {
        if($(this).hasClass('ExpressCheckoutBlockCompleted')) {
            $(this).find('.ChangeLink').click();
        }
    });

    // Capture any loading errors
    $(document).ajaxError(function(event, request, settings) {
        ExpressCheckout.HideLoadingIndicators();
        alert(lang.ExpressCheckoutLoadError);
    });
},

Login: function()
{
    $('#CheckoutLoginError').hide();
    ExpressCheckout.anonymousCheckout = 0;
    ExpressCheckout.createAccount = 0;

    if(ExpressCheckout.validateEmailAddress($('#login_email').val()) == false) {
        alert(lang.LoginEnterValidEmail);
        $('#login_email').focus();
        $('#login_email').select();
        return false;
    }

    if($('#login_pass').val() == '') {
        alert(lang.LoginEnterPassword);
        $('#login_pass').focus();
        return false;
    }

    ExpressCheckout.ShowLoadingIndicator('#LoginForm');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'remote.php',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: 'w=expressCheckoutLogin&'+$('#LoginForm').serialize(),
        success: ExpressCheckout.HandleResponse
    });

    return false;
},

HandleResponse: function(response)
{
    ExpressCheckout.HideLoadingIndicators();

    if(response.completedSteps != undefined) {
        $.each(response.completedSteps, function() {
            var value = document.createTextNode(this.message);
            $('#CheckoutStep'+this.id+' .ExpressCheckoutCompletedContent').html(value);
            $('#CheckoutStep'+this.id).addClass('ExpressCheckoutBlockCompleted');
            ExpressCheckout.completedSteps[ExpressCheckout.completedSteps.length] = this.id;
        });
    }

    if(response.stepContent != undefined) {
        $.each(response.stepContent, function() {
            $('#CheckoutStep'+this.id+' .ExpressCheckoutContent').html(this.content);
            $('#CheckoutStep'+this.id+' .ExpressCheckoutContent .FormField.JSHidden').show();
        });
    }

    ExpressCheckout.HandleResponseStatus(response);
},

HandleResponseStatus: function(response)
{
    if(response.status == 0) {
        if(response.errorContainer) {
            $(response.errorContainer).html(response.errorMessage).show();
        }
        else {
            alert(response.errorMessage);
        }
    }

    if(response.changeStep) {
        ExpressCheckout.ChangeStep(response.changeStep);
        ExpressCheckout.ResetNextSteps();
    }

    // Set focus to a particular field
    if(response.focus) {
        try {
            $(response.focus).focus().select();
        }
        catch(e) { }
    }
},

GuestCheckout: function()
{
    $('#CreateAccountForm').show();
    $('#CheckoutLoginError').hide();

    if($('#CheckoutGuestForm').css('display') != 'none' && !$('#checkout_type_register:checked').val()) {
        type = 'guest';
        ExpressCheckout.anonymousCheckout = 1;
        ExpressCheckout.createAccount = 0;
    }
    else {
        type = 'account';
        ExpressCheckout.anonymousCheckout = 0;
        ExpressCheckout.createAccount = 1;
    }

    ExpressCheckout.ShowLoadingIndicator('#CheckoutGuestForm');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'remote.php',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            w: 'expressCheckoutGetAddressFields',
            type: type
        },
        success: ExpressCheckout.HandleResponse
    });
},

ResetNextSteps:function()
{
    steps = ExpressCheckout.GetSteps();
    var beginReset = false;
    var newCompleted = Array();
    $.each(steps, function(i, step) {
        if(step == ExpressCheckout.currentStep) {
            newCompleted[newCompleted.length] = step;
            beginReset = true;
        }
        else if(beginReset == true) {
            $('#CheckoutStep'+step).removeClass('ExpressCheckoutBlockCompleted');
            $('#CheckoutStep'+step+' .ExpressCheckoutCompletedContent').html('');
        }
    });

    ExpressCheckout.completedSteps = newCompleted;
},

ChangeStep: function(step)
{
    if(typeof(step) == 'undefined') {
        step = ExpressCheckout.CalculateNextStep(ExpressCheckout.currentStep);
    }

    if(step == ExpressCheckout.currentStep) {
        return false;
    }

    $('#CheckoutStep'+ExpressCheckout.currentStep+' .ExpressCheckoutContent').slideUp('slow');
    $('#CheckoutStep'+ExpressCheckout.currentStep).addClass('ExpressCheckoutBlockCollapsed');
    if($.inArray(ExpressCheckout.currentStep, ExpressCheckout.completedSteps) != -1) {
        $('#CheckoutStep'+ExpressCheckout.currentStep).addClass('ExpressCheckoutBlockCompleted');
    }
    $('#CheckoutStep'+step+' .ExpressCheckoutContent').slideDown('slow');
    $('#CheckoutStep'+step).removeClass('ExpressCheckoutBlockCollapsed');
    ExpressCheckout.currentStep = step;
    return false;
},

GetSteps: function()
{
    var steps = Array();
    if(ExpressCheckout.signedIn == 0) {
        steps[steps.length] = 'AccountDetails';
    }
    steps[steps.length] = 'BillingAddress';
    if(!ExpressCheckout.digitalOrder) {
        steps[steps.length] = 'ShippingAddress';
        steps[steps.length] = 'ShippingProvider';
    }
    steps[steps.length] = 'Confirmation';
    steps[steps.length] = 'PaymentDetails';
    return steps;
},

CalculateNextStep: function(currentStep) {
    steps = ExpressCheckout.GetSteps();
    var nextStep = '';
    $.each(steps, function(i, step) {
        if(step == currentStep) {
            nextStep = steps[i + 1];
        }
    });

    if(nextStep) {
        return nextStep;
    }
},

ChooseBillingAddress: function()
{
    // Chosen to use a new address?
    if(!$('#BillingAddressTypeExisting:checked').val() || $('#ChooseBillingAddress').css('display') == 'none') {
        // If creating a new account, validate the account fields as well
        if((ExpressCheckout.anonymousCheckout || ExpressCheckout.createAccount) &&
            !ExpressCheckout.ValidateNewAccount(true)) {
                return false;
        }

        if(!ExpressCheckout.ValidateNewAddress('billing')) {
            return false;
        }

        addressType = 'new';
    }
    // An address wasn't selected
    else if($('.SelectBillingAddress select option:selected').val() == -1) {
        alert(lang.ExpressCheckoutChooseBilling);
        $('.SelectBillingAddress select').focus();
        return false;
    }
    else {
        addressType = 'existing';
    }

    createAppend = '';
    if(ExpressCheckout.createAccount) {
        createAppend = '&createAccount=1';
    }

    // ISC-1214: no script issue in webkit browser, with serialized form submission
    $('noscript').remove();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'remote.php',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: 'w=saveExpressCheckoutBillingAddress&'
            + $('#NewBillingAddress').serialize()
            + '&BillingAddressType=' + addressType
            + createAppend,
        success: ExpressCheckout.HandleResponse
    });
    return false;
},

ChooseShippingAddress: function(copyBilling)
{
    // Chosen to use a new address?
    if(!$('#ShippingAddressTypeExisting:checked').val() || $('#ChooseShippingAddress').css('display') == 'none') {
        if(!ExpressCheckout.ValidateNewAddress('shipping')) {
            return false;
        }

        addressType = 'new';
    }
    // An address wasn't selected
    else if($('.SelectShippingAddress select option:selected').val() == -1) {
        alert(lang.ExpressCheckoutChooseShipping);
        $('.SelectShippingAddress select').focus();
        return false;
    }
    else {
        addressType = 'existing';
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: 'remote.php',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: 'w=saveExpressCheckoutShippingAddress&'
            +$('#NewShippingAddress').serialize()
            +'&ShippingAddressType='+addressType,
        success: ExpressCheckout.HandleResponse
    });
    return false;
},

SetBillingAndShippingAddress: function()
{
    // billing address is pre-selected so update the HTML block content from selected index
    billingAddress = $('.SelectBillingAddress select option:selected').html().substring(0, 58);
    $('#CheckoutStepBillingAddress .ExpressCheckoutCompletedContent').html(billingAddress + '...');
    $('#CheckoutStepBillingAddress').addClass('ExpressCheckoutBlockCompleted');

    // select given shipping address and reset the cart step to ShippingProvider
    ExpressCheckout.ChooseShippingAddress();

    return false;
},

ChooseShippingProvider: function()
{
    // A shipping provider hasn't been selected
    var shippingValid = true;
    $('#CheckoutStepShippingProvider .ShippingProviderList').each(function() {
        if(!$(this).find('input[type=radio]:checked').val()) {
            alert(lang.ExpressCheckoutChooseShipper);
            $(this).find('input[type=radio]').get(0).focus();
            shippingValid = false;
            return false;
        }
    });

    if(shippingValid == false) {
        return false;
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: 'remote.php',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: 'w=saveExpressCheckoutShippingProvider&'+$('#CheckoutStepShippingProvider form').serialize(),
        success: ExpressCheckout.HandleResponse
    });
    return false;
},

ShowLoadingIndicator: function(step) {
    if(typeof(step) == 'undefined') {
        step = 'body';
    }
    $(step).find('.ExpressCheckoutBlock input[type=submit]').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('oldValue', $(this).val());
        $(this).val(lang.ExpressCheckoutLoading);
        $(this).attr('disabled', true);
    });
    $(step).find('.LoadingIndicator').show();
    $('body').css('cursor', 'wait');
},

HideLoadingIndicators: function()
{
    HideLoadingIndicator();
    $('.ExpressCheckoutBlock input[type=submit]').each(function() {
        if($(this).attr('oldValue') && $(this).attr('disabled') == true) {
            $(this).val($(this).attr('oldValue'));
            $(this).attr('disabled', false);
        }
    });
    $('.LoadingIndicator').hide();
    $('body').css('cursor', 'default');
},

LoadOrderConfirmation: function()
{
    postVars.w = 'expressCheckoutShowConfirmation';
    $.ajax({
        url: 'remote.php',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: postVars,
        success: ExpressCheckout.HandleResponse
    });
},

HidePaymentForm: function()
{
    $('#CheckoutStepPaymentDetails').hide();
    $('#CheckoutStepPaymentDetails .ExpressCheckoutContent').html('');
},

LoadPaymentForm: function(provider)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: 'remote.php',
        data: 'w=expressCheckoutLoadPaymentForm&'+$('#CheckoutStepConfirmation form').serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'post',
        success: ExpressCheckout.HandleResponse
    });
},

ShowSingleMethodPaymentForm: function()
{
    $('#CheckoutStepPaymentDetails').show();
    ShowContinueButton();
},

ValidateNewAccount: function()
{
    var password, confirmPassword, formfield = FormField.GetValues(CustomCheckoutFormNewAccount);

    for (var i=0; i<formfield.length; i++) {

        // Check email
        if (formfield[i].privateId == 'EmailAddress') {
            if (ExpressCheckout.validateEmailAddress(formfield[i].value) == false) {
                alert(lang.LoginEnterValidEmail);
                FormField.Focus(formfield[i].field);
                return false;
            }
        }

        if (formfield[i].privateId == 'Password') {
            if(!ExpressCheckout.createAccount) {
                continue;
            }
            password = formfield[i];
        }
        else if(formfield[i].privateId == 'ConfirmPassword') {
            if(!ExpressCheckout.createAccount) {
                continue;
            }
            confirmPassword = formfield[i];
        }

        var rtn = FormField.Validate(formfield[i].field);
        if (!rtn.status) {
            alert(rtn.msg);
            FormField.Focus(formfield[i].field);
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Compare the passwords
    if (ExpressCheckout.createAccount && password && password.value !== confirmPassword.value) {
        alert(lang.AccountPasswordsDontMatch);
        FormField.Focus(confirmPassword.field);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
},

BuildAddressLine: function(type)
{
    var fieldList = {
        'FirstName' : '',
        'LastName' : '',
        'Company' : '',
        'AddressLine1' : '',
        'City' : '',
        'State' : '',
        'Zip' : '',
        'Country' : ''
    };

    if(type == 'billing') {
        var formId = CustomCheckoutFormBillingAddress;
    }
    else {
        var formId = CustomCheckoutFormShippingAddress;
    }

    var formfields = FormField.GetValues(formId);
    var addressLine = '';

    for (var i=0; i<formfields.length; i++) {
        fieldList[formfields[i].privateId] = formfields[i].value;
    }

    for (var i in fieldList) {
        var val = fieldList[i];
        if (val !== '') {
            if(addressLine != '' && i != 'LastName') {
                addressLine += ', ';
            } else if(i == 'LastName') {
                addressLine += ' ';
            }

            addressLine += val;
        }
    };

    return addressLine;
},

ValidateNewAddress: function(lowerType, resultOnly)
{
    if (resultOnly !== true) {
        resultOnly = false;
    }

    if(lowerType == 'billing') {
        var formId = CustomCheckoutFormBillingAddress;
    } else {
        var formId = CustomCheckoutFormShippingAddress;
    }

    var formfields = FormField.GetValues(formId);
    var hasErrors = false;

    for (var i=0; i<formfields.length; i++) {

        var rtn = FormField.Validate(formfields[i].field);

        if (!rtn.status) {
            if (!resultOnly) {
                alert(rtn.msg);
            }

            FormField.Focus(formfields[i].field);
            hasErrors = true;
            return false;
        }
    }

    if(hasErrors == true) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
},

validateEmailAddress: function(email)
{
    if(email.indexOf('@') == -1 || email.indexOf('.') == -1) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;

},

ToggleAddressType: function(address, type)
{
    if(type == 'Select') {
        $('.Select'+address+'Address').show();
        $('.Add'+address+'Address').hide();
    }
    else {
        $('.Add'+address+'Address').show();
        $('.Select'+address+'Address').hide();
    }
},

SelectedPaymentProvider: function() {
    var paymentProvider = '';

    // Get the ID of the selected payment provider
    if($('#use_store_credit').css('display') != "none") {
        if($('#store_credit:checked').val()) {
            if($('#credit_provider_list').css('display') != "none") {
                paymentProvider = $('#credit_provider_list input:checked');
            }
        }
        else {
            paymentProvider = $('#provider_list input:checked');
        }
    }
    else {
        paymentProvider = $('#provider_list input:checked');
    }
    return paymentProvider
},

ConfirmPaymentProvider: function()
{
    //if terms and conditions is enabled and the customer didn't tick agree terms and conditions
    if($('.CheckoutHideOrderTermsAndConditions').css('display') != "none" && $('#AgreeTermsAndConditions').prop('checked') != true){
        alert(lang.TickArgeeTermsAndConditions);
        return false;
    }

    if(!confirm_payment_provider()) {
        return false;
    }

    var paymentProvider = ExpressCheckout.SelectedPaymentProvider();

    if(paymentProvider != '' && $(paymentProvider).hasClass('ProviderHasPaymentForm')) {
        var providerName = $('.ProviderName'+paymentProvider.val()).html();
        $('#CheckoutStepConfirmation .ExpressCheckoutCompletedContent').html(providerName);
        ExpressCheckout.LoadPaymentForm($(paymentProvider).val());
        return false;
    }
    else {
        ExpressCheckout.HidePaymentForm();
        return true;
    }
},

ApplyCouponCode: function()
{
    if($('#couponcode').val() == '') {
        alert(lang.EnterCouponCode);
        $('#couponcode').focus();
        return false;
    }

    // Reload the order confirmation
    $.ajax({
        url: 'remote.php',
        data: 'w=getExpressCheckoutConfirmation&'+$('#CheckoutStepConfirmation form').serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'post',
        success: ExpressCheckout.HandleResponse
    });

    return false;
},

UncheckPaymentProvider: function()
{
    $('#provider_list input').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('checked', false);
    });
}
```

};

Comment: Were you ever able to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I could get the top three accordions open at the same time (the bottom ones are shipping methods and order confirmations, which I think are tied to the previous steps)

```
$('.ExpressCheckoutBlockCollapsed').addClass('ExpressCheckoutBlockCompleted')
$('.ExpressCheckoutBlockCollapsed').removeClass('ExpressCheckoutBlockCollapsed')
```

I think if you have this code trigger on the checkout page, it might help a little. Regarding changing the order of elements, chrome console shows the following IDs associated with these elements, can't you anchor them to different locations, as you need it?

```
$('.ExpressCheckoutBlockCollapsed').addClass('ExpressCheckoutBlockCompleted')
[
<div class=​"Clear ExpressCheckoutBlock ExpressCheckoutBlockCompleted" id=​"CheckoutStepBillingAddress" style=​"cursor:​ default;​">​…​</div>​
, 
<div class=​"Clear ExpressCheckoutBlock ExpressCheckoutBlockCollapsed ExpressCheckoutBlockCompleted" id=​"CheckoutStepShippingAddress" style>​…​</div>​
, 
<div class=​"Clear ExpressCheckoutBlock ExpressCheckoutBlockCollapsed ExpressCheckoutBlockCompleted" id=​"CheckoutStepShippingProvider" style>​…​</div>​
, 
<div class=​"Clear ExpressCheckoutBlock ExpressCheckoutBlockCollapsed ExpressCheckoutBlockCompleted" id=​"CheckoutStepConfirmation">​…​</div>​
, 
<div class=​"Clear ExpressCheckoutBlock ExpressCheckoutBlockCollapsed ExpressCheckoutBlockCompleted" id=​"CheckoutStepPaymentDetails" style=​"display:​ none">​…​</div>​
]
```