# Simplify BigCommerce Checkout Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, bigcommerce

I have a client that is using BigCommerce and would like to simplify the checkout page. He'd like all the fields on one page but doesn't like how there's accordions. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to default all the fields to open? I am familiar with JavaScript to an extent but couldn't do this from scratch.

There's another article: [TRUE single checkout page on BigCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18322878/true-single-checkout-page-on-bigcommerce)

but I'm not sure how to go about putting it in the site or creating a trigger. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're going to need to be extremely familiar with javascript to make this work, but it's completely do-able. The platform is open enough that you can easily make the calls to the different steps and return error messages as users input their data.

Answer (score 0):

I actually decided that instead of risking the potential complications with overriding their JavaScript, I just edited the physical html files from the theme.